# Create flexible constructor method accepting either String or &str

Tags: rust, overloading, traits

I am completely new to rust. I created a program to store information about persons to get in touch with the language:

`person.rs`

```rust
pub struct Person {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    pub age: u8
}


impl Person {
    pub fn new(firstname: String, lastname: String, age: u8) -> Person {
        return Person { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, age: age };
    }

    pub fn from_str(firstname: &str, lastname: &str, age: u8) -> Person {
        return Person::new(firstname.to_string(), lastname.to_string(), age);
    }

    pub fn name(&self) -> String {
        return self.firstname.to_owned() + " " + &self.lastname;
    }
}
```

`main.rs`

```rust
mod person;
use person::Person;


fn main() {
    let me = Person::from_str("John", "Doe", 42);
    println!("{} is {} years old.", me.name(), me.age);
}
```

I understand, that there is no function overloading in rust.
However, I have read about a concept called "traits", which I have not fully understood.
Do they behave similar to templates in C++ (I'm also not a C++ pro)?
Is there another way, e.g. using traits, so that I can write `Person::new()` to accept either `String` or `&str`?

I tried this to no avail:

`person.rs`

```rust
pub struct Person {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    pub age: u8
}


impl Person {
    /*
    pub fn new(firstname: String, lastname: String, age: u8) -> Person {
        return Person { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, age: age };
    }

    pub fn from_str(firstname: &str, lastname: &str, age: u8) -> Person {
        return Person::new(firstname.to_string(), lastname.to_string(), age);
    }
    */
    
    pub fn new<T>(firstname: &T, lastname: &T, age: u8) -> Person {
        return Person::new(firstname.to_string(), lastname.to_string(), age);
    }

    pub fn name(&self) -> String {
        return self.firstname.to_owned() + " " + &self.lastname;
    }
}
```

`main.rs`

```rust
mod person;
use person::Person;


fn main() {
    let me = Person::new("John", "Doe", 42);
    println!("{} is {} years old.", me.name(), me.age);
}
```

Resulting in:

```
$ rustc main.rs -o main
error[E0599]: the method `to_string` exists for reference `&T`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> person.rs:20:38
   |
20 |         return Person::new(firstname.to_string(), lastname.to_string(), age);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&T` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `T: std::fmt::Display`
           which is required by `T: ToString`
           `&T: std::fmt::Display`
           which is required by `&T: ToString`

error[E0599]: the method `to_string` exists for reference `&T`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> person.rs:20:60
   |
20 |         return Person::new(firstname.to_string(), lastname.to_string(), age);
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&T` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `T: std::fmt::Display`
           which is required by `T: ToString`
           `&T: std::fmt::Display`
           which is required by `&T: ToString`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> main.rs:6:14
   |
6  |     let me = Person::new("John", "Doe", 42);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `str`
note: required by a bound in `Person::new`
  --> person.rs:19:16
   |
19 |     pub fn new<T>(firstname: &T, lastname: &T, age: u8) -> Person {
   |                ^ required by this bound in `Person::new`
help: consider relaxing the implicit `Sized` restriction
  --> person.rs:19:17
   |
19 |     pub fn new<T: ?Sized>(firstname: &T, lastname: &T, age: u8) -> Person {
   |                 ++++++++

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust has generics, not templates. Generics can be bounded by traits, which provide a system for standard interfaces.

In your case, what you need is a trait that will give you a `String` from either a `String` or a `&str`. You have a few options, but I'd choose `Into<String>`.

You can do this:

```rust
    pub fn new(firstname: impl Into<String>, lastname: impl Into<String>, age: u8) -> Person {
        Person {
            firstname: firstname.into(),
            lastname: lastname.into(),
            age
        }
    }
```

Essentially what this says is:

- new is a function
- which takes three arguments
- the first two args can be any type that implements `Into<String>`
- the last argument must be a `u8`

[`Into<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html) is a standard trait in Rust meant for the use in conversions. It defines an associated `fn into(self) -> T` that takes the given object by value and returns the target `T`.

`Into` is really just the complementary helper trait to [`From<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) which has an associated `fn from(other: T) -> Self` that takes some other type and returns the type you want.

`From` has a reflexive implementation, which essentially means that for any type, you can do `T::from(x)` where `x` is of type `T`. This also applies to `Into`, so any type can be converted `into` itself, which is why `String` will work when the compiler expects `Into<String>`.

Comment: Thank you. I first thought, you forgot the return statement, because it did not compile with a semicolon after the constructor call. But when leaving it out, rust seems to implicitly return it. Strange new world.

Comment: Implicit returns are really cool once you get used to them. Curly brace blocks take on the value of their last expression. It's an elegant feature that has all sorts of implications: functions automatically return their final expression; `if`/`else` blocks can be used as expressions the way you would use `?`+`:` in other languages; `match` blocks can be statements or expressions; and much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept `impl Into<String>`:

```
pub fn new(firstname: impl Into<String>, lastname: impl Into<String>, age: u8) -> Person {
    Person {
        firstname: firstname.into(),
        lastname: lastname.into(),
        age: age,
    }
}
```

`impl Trait` in parameter position is a short way to declare that a parameter is generic. You could alternatively write out the function signature with explicitly named generic types:

```
pub fn new<F, L>(firstname: F, lastname: L, age: u8) -> Person
where
    F: Into<String>,
    L: Into<String>,
```

To explain the use of `Into` <sup><sub>in excessive detail</sub></sup>:

1. `Into` is the inverse of `From` thanks to this blanket implementation:

   ```
   impl<T, U> const Into<U> for T
   where
       U: ~const From<T>,
   {
       fn into(self) -> U {
           U::from(self)
       }
   }
   ```

   Whenever `impl From<T> for U` exists, so does the matching `impl Into<U> for T`.
2. The standard library provides a [variety of such implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3C%26%27a%20String%3E) for `String`:

   ```
   impl From<char> for String
   impl From<Box<str>> for String
   impl From<&str> for String
   impl From<&String> for String
   impl From<&mut str> for String
   impl From<Cow<'_, str>> for String
   ```

   Thanks to `impl From<&str> for String` you can build a `String` from a `&str`.
3. Additionally, there is a [blanket implementation for all `T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-13):

   ```
   impl<T> From<T> for T {
       fn from(t: T) -> T {
           t
       }
   }
   ```

   Any type can be trivially converted into itself. That means `impl From<String> for String` is also available as a zero-cost conversion.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation of generics. I will look into it further.